# load jsonobject in recyclerview with volley

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am using volley for loading data but I cannot display jsonobject on `recyclerview`. how to display jsonobject data on recyclerview?or how to convert jsonobject to StringRequest because i can display StringRequest on recyclerview?

API URL=http://alexer.ir/api/country/IR

build gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile files('libs/KGJsonConverter.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
```

Item

```
 public class Item implements Serializable {
 public  int status;
public int number;
public String site;
public float daily_time_on_site;
public float description;
public float daily_pageviews;
public float traffic_from_search;
public float total_sites_linking_in;

        }
```

ItemAdapter

```
     public class ItemAdapter extends 
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

 private Context contax;
private ArrayList<Item> itemlist;

public  ItemAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Item >itemlist){
    this.contax=context;
    this.itemlist=itemlist;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view=inflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_cardview_layout,parent,false);
     ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder=new ItemViewHolder(view);
    return itemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Item item=itemlist.get(position);

    holder.number.setText(item.number);
    holder.site.setText(item.site);
    holder.daily_time_on_site.setText(""+item.daily_time_on_site);
    holder.description.setText(""+item.description);
    holder.daily_pageviews.setText(""+item.daily_pageviews);
    holder.traffic_from_search.setText(""+item.traffic_from_search);
    holder.total_sites_linking_in.setText(""+item.total_sites_linking_in);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemlist !=null){
        return itemlist.size();

    }

 return 0;
   }

  public  static  class  ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
  {


public CardView cvItem;
public TextView number;
public TextView site;
public TextView daily_time_on_site;
public TextView description;
public TextView daily_pageviews;
public TextView traffic_from_search;
public TextView total_sites_linking_in;


public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    cvItem=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvItem);
    number= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
    site= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.site);
    daily_time_on_site= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.daily_time_on_site);
    description= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    daily_pageviews= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.daily_pageviews);
    traffic_from_search= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.traffic_from_search);
    total_sites_linking_in= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.total_sites_linking_in);



       }
      }

         }
```

MySingleton

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView rvItem;
CardView cvItem;
TextView mTxtDisplay ,mtt;
final   String TAG ="MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTxtDisplay);

    rvItem= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItem);
    rvItem.setHasFixedSize(true);
    cvItem= (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cvItem);
    LinearLayoutManager manager=new 
 LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true);
    rvItem.setLayoutManager(manager);
    String url="http://alexer.ir/api/country/IR";



  //jsonobject start


    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new 
    Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        String data=response.getString("data");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


   ArrayList<Item> productList = new JsonConverter<Item>().toArrayList(data, 
     Item.class);


                        ItemAdapter adapter= new 
    ItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(),productList);
                        rvItem.setAdapter(adapter);





                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }







                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

     // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);


  }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your `MainActivity` as below:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView rvItem;
    CardView cvItem;
    TextView mTxtDisplay, mtt;

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Item> productList;
    ItemAdapter adapter;

    final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Context
        mContext = this;

        mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTxtDisplay);

        rvItem= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItem);
        rvItem.setHasFixedSize(true);
        cvItem= (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cvItem);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true);
        rvItem.setLayoutManager(manager);

        // Values
        productList = new ArrayList<Item>();

        // Adapter
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(mContext, productList);
        rvItem.setAdapter(adapter);

        // API
        String url = "http://alexer.ir/api/country/IR";

        //jsonObject start
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new
            Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");


                        // Looping through all objects and storing
                        // them in array list
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                            String number = jsonObject.getString("number");
                            String site = jsonObject.getString("site");
                            String description = jsonObject.getString("description");
                            String daily_time_on_site = jsonObject.getString("daily_time_on_site");
                            String daily_pageviews = jsonObject.getString("daily_pageviews");
                            String traffic_from_search = jsonObject.getString("traffic_from_search");
                            String total_sites_linking_in = jsonObject.getString("total_sites_linking_in");

                            // Item
                            Item item = new Item(number, site, description, daily_time_on_site, daily_pageviews,
                                    traffic_from_search, total_sites_linking_in);

                            // Add to list
                            productList.add(Item);
                        }

                        // Notifying adapter about data changes, so that the
                        // list renders with new data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
    }
}
```

**Update `Item` class as below:**

```
public class Item {

    private int status;
    private String number;
    private String site;
    private String description;
    private String daily_time_on_site;
    private String daily_pageviews;
    private String traffic_from_search;
    private String total_sites_linking_in;

    public Item(String number, String site, String description, String daily_time_on_site, String daily_pageviews,
                String traffic_from_search, String total_sites_linking_in) {
        this.number = number;
        this.site = site;
        this.description = description;
        this.daily_time_on_site = daily_time_on_site;
        this.daily_pageviews = daily_pageviews;
        this.traffic_from_search = traffic_from_search;
        this.total_sites_linking_in = total_sites_linking_in;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDaily_time_on_site() {
        return daily_time_on_site;
    }

    public void setDaily_time_on_site(String daily_time_on_site) {
        this.daily_time_on_site = daily_time_on_site;
    }

    public String getDaily_pageviews() {
        return daily_pageviews;
    }

    public void setDaily_pageviews(String daily_pageviews) {
        this.daily_pageviews = daily_pageviews;
    }

    public String getTraffic_from_search() {
        return traffic_from_search;
    }

    public void setTraffic_from_search(String traffic_from_search) {
        this.traffic_from_search = traffic_from_search;
    }

    public String getTotal_sites_linking_in() {
        return total_sites_linking_in;
    }

    public void setTotal_sites_linking_in(String total_sites_linking_in) {
        this.total_sites_linking_in = total_sites_linking_in;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you very much